# Can't get the columns of galleries when the user set the column number to 3 if there are 2 galleries?

Tags: gallery

I'm detecting if the user has a gallery in his post:

```
$gallery = get_post_gallery( $post->ID, False );
$gallery_images = explode( ',', $gallery['ids'] );
```

And at times I'd like to see how many columns it has:

```
var_dump( $gallery['columns'] );
```

This works for 2 columns, it returns `2` but if I were to set the columns to 3, it breaks, throwing the error:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: columns in <b>C:\file.php</b> on line <b>45</b>
```

Note that 4, 5 columns work just fine, but 3 won't. **This only happens when there's a second gallery in the post.**

How is this possible?

Comment: I just tested this and yes, I can also see this behaviour! My first thought was that it has to do with the default setting. 3 columns seems to be the default gallery column count in WordPress. Sorry I have no fix for you in the moment.

Comment: @LWS-Mo Great. At least I know it's a bug.

Comment: I found that if you select the default 3 columns, the `column` key dont exists in the array. So you could check if the array-key `column` exists. See my answer...

Answer (score 3):

OK, I just tested this a little further. Indeed, if you select 3 columns (the default WP gallery column count) and do a `var_dump( $gallery );` you will see that there is no `column` key in the array.  (like for example with 4 columns `["columns"]=> "4"`).
You can maybe do something like this:

```
$gallery = get_post_gallery( $post->ID, false );

if (array_key_exists( 'columns', $gallery )) {
    echo $gallery['columns'];
} else {
    echo 'default WP 3 columns';
}
```

Comment: `$columns = isset( $gallery['columns'] ) ? $gallery['columns'] : '3'; //Fix` Did it for me.

Comment: @coolpasta oh yes, good idea :)

Comment: @coolpasta `isset( $gallery['columns'] )` will cause notices on some PHP versions...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I only need to support 5.4, 5.3 if I feel nice. Can you explain further?

Comment: @coolpasta what you want to check is array_key_exists - it’s not the same as isset( $array[$key] ).